# Sending an email to all users via contact form

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, phpmailer

I am trying to pull together all my users to send an email out to them from a contact form. I am using Wordpress to house all my users.

I have a script which loops through all my users but need to be able it to send them all at once:

```
<?php
$wp_user_search = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, user_email FROM $wpdb->users ORDER BY ID");

foreach ( $wp_user_search as $userid ) {
    $user_id       = (int) $userid->ID;
    $user_login    = stripslashes($userid->user_login);
    $email  = stripslashes($userid->user_email);

    $return  = '';
    $return .= "\t" . '<p>'. $email .'</p>' . "\n";

    print($return);
}
?>



        <form action="../mailadmin.php" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>">
            <input type="text" name="subject" value="" placeholder="Subject..." style="padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #EEEEEE; width:100%;"> 
            <br><br>
            <textarea onkeyup="textAreaAdjust(this)" name="contentfield" style="max-width: 100%; min-width: 100%; min-height: 200px; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #EEEEEE;  height:auto; overflow:visible;" placeholder="Please begin typing your message..."></textarea>
            <br><br>
            <button class="amendbutton" type="submit" style="padding: 10px;">Send Message</button>
        </form>
    </div>    
</div>
```

My second file which handles the mail function is causing me some difficulty as it does not appear to be recognising my named fields so I am wanting to send it to all users, send through a subject and message but I keep getting errors stating undefined variables?

This is the part of the script that is causing me bother too:

```
$mail->addAddress(stripslashes($_POST["email"]));

$mail->Subject = 'Subject header';
$mail->Body    = 'Subject: ' . $_POST["subject"] . 'Message: ' . $_POST["contentfield"];
```

Comment: So all you need is to add mail(...) in the loop and learn how to create a POST form in php? Using IDS in the html is a good start.

Comment: What is $mail ? PHPMailer ?

Comment: Where am I adding the add mail() sorry I have been working all day my eyes are beginning to hurt!

Comment: @djidi that is correct yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to add email field in your HTML, just add BCC field in your code to send email :

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();

$wp_user_search = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->users ORDER BY ID");

foreach ( $wp_user_search as $user )
   $mail->AddBCC($user->user_email, $user->user_name); // first var is email, second is name

$mail->Subject = 'Subject header';
$mail->Body    = 'Subject: ' . $_POST["subject"] . 'Message: ' . $_POST["contentfield"];
```

[Check this](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.html) to see all methods for PHPMailer.

Comment: So that will send out to all of my users stored in my wordpress backend?

Comment: You have to use your code to get all your users when you send email instead of doing it in HTML and add BCC

Comment: I am confused as to where this needs to go and what I need to do to my php mailer script to ensure they are both talking, would you be kind enough to use my code and edit it?

Comment: So will this from the contact form once filled in send a message to all of the user that are in the wordpress user database?

Comment: Yes. This is the goal of $mail->AddBCC(), add multiple recipients (in blind carbon copy)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56360/discussion-between-user3725879-and-djidi).

Comment: I have began a discussion with you, would you be kind enough to assist me?